# iframe click link it opens in parent page rather than in iframe page

Tags: javascript, iframe

User clicks on URL hyperlink (http://example.com) within a iframe dialog window, dialog window closes and link is open in parent page.

how do you open the clicked link in the parent page instead of inside the iframe page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the `iFrame` page:

```
<a href="javascript:parent.window.location.href='http://cnn.com/';">Go to CNN</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

If its an `<a />` tag then set the `target` attribute to `_parent`

This will open the linked document in the parent frameset