# Button in parent iframe click inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

i'm trying to make a nav bar with the contents below in an iframe and i'm wanting the nav bar buttons when clicked to load a page in the lower iframe.

The iframe and main page will be on the same server // domain, so i was wondering if anyone could recommend something ?

I had a lil Google and found this:
[iframe click link it opens in parent page rather than in iframe page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044788/iframe-click-link-it-opens-in-parent-page-rather-than-in-iframe-page)

and tried changing parent to child but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering an iFrame with name attribute of `foo`.

```
<iframe name="foo" src="index.html"></iframe>
```

Use a link with target `foo`.

```
<a href="about.html" target="foo">About</a>
```

Should work as expected.

Comment: Happy to help. :)